# executeUpdate returns negative value on large table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Running mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.44-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

I have written a Java servlet which runs executeUpdate() on an SQL export statement and returns integer value.

```
    String sql = "SELECT TRIM(CONCAT( field1, CallDate, field2, Minutes, field3, field4 )) INTO OUTFILE '/var/www/html/pld/CDROUT/test2.txt' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM CDRLEC";
    Statement s = dbConPLD.createStatement();
    int rows = s.executeUpdate(sql);
    // Returns number of rows affected by this process
    return (rows == 0) ? 0 : rows;

    // Then, in the calling servlet, I have this        
    String returnOutput = Integer.toString(rows);
    return returnOutput;
```

This works fine with small tables of just a few thousand rows.  When I run this on a table with 40,000 rows (40,895 to be exact), I get a large negative number: -24641.  Same results when I execute an import statement.  The file is 14MB.

Also the same result when I delete all the imported recods from the table: "delete from CDRLEC".  I get -24641 rows processed.

The export and import are successfully executed. It's just that instead of seeing 40895 I see -24641 for rows. Can someone help me figure out what the heck is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I was using the JDBC Driver:MariaDB connector/J 1.4.2

I resolved the issue by switching to: JDBC Driver:MySQL-AB JDBC Driver mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga

Code works as expected now.